# Type guard on conditional parameter type

Tags: typescript, generic-type-argument, conditional-types

Why is this code not working ?

Typescript could easily guess that a variable of type `(T extends '1' ? '1' : never)` will never be `false`, so that `NonFalse<TypeWithCondition<T>>` is exactly the same than `true | (T extends '1' ? '1' : never)`.

Is it a Typescript bug ? Should it be posted as a Feature Request ?

```
type TypeWithCondition<T> = boolean | (T extends '1' ? '1' : never);

type NonFalse<T> = Exclude<T, false>;

const logNonFalse = <T>(b: NonFalse<TypeWithCondition<T>>) => {
    console.log(b);
};

const test1 = <T>(a: TypeWithCondition<T>) => {
    if (a === false) throw new Error("Can't be false");
    logNonFalse(a);
    // Error : Argument of type 'true | ([T] extends ["1"] ? "1" : never)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true'.
    //  Type '[T] extends ["1"] ? "1" : never' is not assignable to type 'true'.
    //    Type '"1"' is not assignable to type 'true'.(2345)
};
```

Comment: The `T` in `test1` is being inferred as `unknown`, since it's unclear what values are allowed as an input to that generic. Can you clarify what exactly the allowed input values to this function would be, or otherwise expand on what you are trying to test for with the conditional type?

Comment: @JacobGillespie thanks for your comment. Yes, Typescript can't guessed what is `T` but it doesn't matter. It can be anything. What I want to do is calling a function (`logNonFalse` here) on a "subtype" (`TypeWithCondition<T>` without `false` here) of a generic conditional type (`TypeWithCondition<T> = boolean | (T extends '1' ? '1' : never)` here).

Comment: Because `unknown` could be anything, that is causing some of the issue here - some `T`s in this example are different from other `T`s, so it can't properly infer what's allowed. I understand you want to call logNonFalse with the generic, but it's not clear what the generic represents. What are the values you want to allow as input to `logNonFalse`? Anything other than false? What does `T extends "1"...` represent?

Comment: But whatever is `T` we should have `true | (T extends '1' ? '1' : never) extends NonFalse<TypeWithCondition<T>>'.
For `logNonFalse` I want anything that is not equal to false.
`T extends "1"...` is just a simple case of a conditional type (I want to achieve something more complicated that I have reduced to this example).

Comment: If you're just wanting to prevent passing `false` to `logNonFalse`, you can do this by removing the `TypeWithCondition` from inside the `NonFalse`: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwGIEMA2BnCAeAKgPigF4oBRADwGM0BXAEx1wBooAzdLfAKC9ZoUrAAloiho4Ac3jIOjfAAoARgC5YiVJjkBKKAG8uUQ1EqIMcNBAB04iUq1cAvjxvSNWeQHIAFhDTiP9i7qsvLsmoGSriHAAE40EFpAA). Otherwise feel free to add more detail to your question for the more complicated case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is not yet able to handle that. Cf https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38863